# Can I drag a DOM element with Javascript code only? (like If I dragged it with my mouse)

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, draggable

I'm learning drag and drop (using VueJS), but I'm trying to move any DOM element with only javascript code, not using the mouse.

For example this simple div:

```
<div id="myDiv">My Div Text</div>
```

with `draggable=true` I can drag and drop it somewhere with the mouse, but I was wondering if I can make the move/drag by code, saying JS to grab that  and move it to anywhere I want (top/right absolute position for example), replacing the user mouse. Is that something I can do somehow?

Comment: `position: absolute` and change `top` and `left` of the element

Comment: Do you want the _effect_ of dragging an element, or just want to move it?

Comment: @MikeBrockington Yes! Like human made the drag/move with its mouse

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to programmatically simulate DnD using the [Drag and Drop API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API).